# Calculate straight line from scattered points

Tags: geometry

I have some scattered 3D points (2d solution is sufficient). I want find different straight lines passing through (at least three points makes line) which are laying nearby (say for example 10 units). A single point could be part of different lines.

Comment: "I want [to] find different straight lines passing through (at least three points makes line) which are laying nearby (say for example 10 units)." is not a sentence, so it's hard to tell what you want to do.

Comment: if a line is passing through only 2 points ignore this line

Comment: Call your set of points S. Am I right that you want to find all subsets s ⊆ S of cardinality at least 3, such that the points in s are "nearly" collinear?

Comment: I read your question like this (correct me, if I'm wrong):
1. I have a cloud of scattered points on a 2D plane.
2. I want to determine, if three of them line up in a way.
3. Since they most certainly will not lie up 100% perfect I want to allow a distance of 10 units from the third point to the line.

If this is the case, you might calculate the perpendicular distance from the third point c to the line a-b and compare this to 10.

Comment: I do not want to determine if three of them line up. Rather I want to make all possible lines where a line has at least three points or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine whether 3 points (a,b,c) are in a line, use cross-products (2D or 3D):

```
V = (Vx, Vy, Vz)
Vab = b - a
Vac = c - a 
CrossProd (V,W) = (VyWz - VzWy, VzWx - WzVx, VxWy - WxVy)
```

If `CrossProd(Vab, Vac)` is zero, then the points `(a, b, c)` are colinear. Actually the cross product is proportional to the area of the triangle `(a, b ,c)`, so you can set a small non-zero tolerance if needed.

Re. tolerance.

The distance from `b` to the line `Vac` is given by:

```
d = length(CrossProd(Vab, Vac))/ length(Vac)
```

You can probably compare this with an absolute tolerance given your problem description. Alternatively you might use:

```
sin(theta) = length(CrossProd(Vab, Vac))/ length(Vac)/ length(Vab)
```

Then `theta` is the angle between the two vectors and can be compared with a fixed tolerance.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think a constant non-Zero tolerance or a tolerance which depends on the distance between the points to be worked out